# Python data output to Excel

Tags: python, excel, python-requests

While spending hours attempting to figure out ways to import stats to an Excel file I came across a version of this script that I've attempted to use in Python. When executing I get the following error below the second `csv_output` portion of the script:

> `KeyError: 0`

I'm just beginning to learn the nuances of Python and can't really figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm currently using Python 3.6 and Windows 10. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import requests
import csv

url = "http://stats.nba.com/stats/leagueLeaders?
LeagueID=00&PerMode=PerGame&Scope=S&Season=2017-
18&SeasonType=Regular+Season&StatCategory=PTS"

data = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
entries = data.json()

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(entries['resultSet'][0]['headers'])
    csv_output.writerows(entries['resultSet'][0]['rowSet'])
```

Comment: `entries['resultSet']` is a `dict`, and doesn't have a key `0`. I recommend printing it and modifying your code to fit the shape of the data

Comment: Add `print data` after you get it with `requests.get()`.

Comment: From your code it's expecting a 'resultSet' that has a list of values, but the problem is that it doesn't exist in the JSON data you read in

Comment: @MrJLP I ran the script in Powershell with 'print (data)' below the request and got <response [200]>, not sure what that means.

Comment: 200 means the response was ok. You need to actually see what's in the response body. You have plenty more to figure out

Answer (score 0):

1. I dont see a module named requests. Perhaps try urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=5)
2. The URL is not correct. If you just open using your browser, it leads to a error. Perhaps check your URL again.

Comment: 1. I'm not sure what you mean by not seeing a module

Comment: 2. When I select the link within this page and right click "go-to" the link doesn't work, but when I copy/paste it works. That makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

entries['resultset'] is a dict object and it doesn't have '0' key.
It has only 'headers', 'rowset', 'name'.

Just remove '[0]' from the below two lines of code, this will work.

```
    csv_output.writerow(entries['resultSet']['headers'])
    csv_output.writerows(entries['resultSet']['rowSet'])
```

Comment: Ugh, I was hoping this would work. Unfortunately when I tried this was the result.    TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Try encoding strings to byte format. [x.encode('utf8') for x in entries['resultset']['headers']]

Comment: I will give that a shot but before I do I'm going to ask you a pretty basic question. Being a new Python user I'm not that familiar with how to execute scripts. Right now I edit within the Notepad, save as Sample.py and then type Python Sample.py into Powershell. Could this method have something to do with my problems?

Comment: Nope your executing procedure has nothing to do with the error. You can search online for python IDE's which will make coding a lot easier

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. I replaced my line of code with yours and I get this           `csv_output.writerows(entries['resultSet']['rowSet'])
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
  import pandas as pd
    data = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
    entries = data.json()
    Header=entries['resultSet']['headers']
    data =entries['resultSet']['rowSet']
    filename='c:\\test\\NBA.xlsx'           

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)    
    df.columns=Header
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet1', index=False,startrow=0 , startcol=0)
    writer.save()
```